# Texturing deformation through a sequence of meshes

Tags: texturing, uv

I have several (externally generated) two-mesh sequences representing undeformed/deformed objects.  I would like to visualize these deformations using texture mappings on the meshes.

In particular, I would like to place a texture on the undeformed object, and have it deform along with the mapping to the deformed object.  The mesh connectivity between undeformed/deformed is the same.

Is there an established method for doing this in Blender?  I have heard that this can be done using "shape keys", although I do not know what this means.  I am very new to Blender and graphics software in general, so basic advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.  I did not use shape keys at all.

This can be done by copying the UV-mapping from the source mesh onto the target mesh (c.f. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/layout_management.html).

Since both objects have the same topology, this is straightforward.